# Delphi Firemonkey get list of Audio driver/ device

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I get list of Audio (sound) driver/device name for Windows & MacOS X?

Comment: Did you even try googling? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfZSNfv2U0A

Comment: You want to list of drivers to do what? Capture sound, play sound, list drivers on screen?

Comment: This only provide microphone list not the sound device names.

Comment: This is why you should strive to ask a clear question: what do you want to do, why? what have you tried. What problem are you trying to solve? Your question is unclear and thus you get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want [to record audio in FMX](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Media.TAudioCaptureDevice), do:

```
var
  AudioCapture : TAudioCaptureDevice;
begin
  // Get access to the default audio capture device
  AudioCapture:= TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;
  if Assigned(AudioCapture) then
  begin
     //do something
  end;
end;
```

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Media.TAudioCaptureDevice

If you want to play sound/audio in FMX [use `TMediaPlayer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer)

For an overview of Audio/Video services in FMX see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Audio-Video_in_FireMonkey

Comment: This only provide microphone list not the sound device names, what I need the name of sound card.